# Reusing a CTFrameSetter which was created using CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString()?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-text

I have seen multiple mentions of the framesetter being "expensive" I have a couple of different attributed strings which are laid out independently of one another, is there a way to "reuse" the framesetter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html) `CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString` and `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` both return an immutable object. Not going to be able to reuse them, unfortunately.